# Dumb Noob question: Terminal is stuck in bash edit mode

Tags: pantheon-terminal, bash

I entered sudo bash and I can't get back to the normal command prompt mode. Exit just closes the terminal. A restart didn't help either.

I would like to exit the bash mode so I don't mess anything up. Thanks!

Comment: `sudo bash` causes the shell to work with root account. What you exactly did? What do you mean by *normal command prompt mode*?

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the user back to your normal user (username)

```
su username
```

Additional you can run `sudo -k` to emtpy the password cache, so next time you run a sudo command you have to enter the password again.

Answer (score 0):

Does running the command `reset` help?